# How to call One bundle entity query in another bundle symfony 2

Tags: entity-framework, symfony

I have two bundles added in my symfony 2 project. 
1) Api Bundle
2) Project Bundle.
          Project Bundle contains Member entity. I want to access this entity for login setup for member in API bundle controller. But I am below error when I tried to access it.
Unknown Entity namespace alias 'TestProjectBundle'.

```
$rsmember = $this->getDoctrine()                      
  ->getRepository('TestProjectBundle:Member')                       
  ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
```

How do I call This In my API bundle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call entity using `BundleLogicalName:EntityName` so, since you have `ProjectBundle` so you should call it:

```
$rsmember = $this->getDoctrine()                      
  ->getRepository('ProjectBundle:Member')                       
  ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
```

> The AppBundle:Product string is a shortcut you can use anywhere in
>   Doctrine instead of the full class name of the entity (i.e.
>   AppBundle\Entity\Product). As long as your entity lives under the
>   Entity namespace of your bundle, this will work.

Check [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database)

Comment: Yes I have change TestProjectBundle:Member from ProjectBundle:Member. It works fine now.